# Uploaded files are empty

Tags: google-drive-api

I’m debugging WinForms application, which makes requests to Google Drive Api using Service Account. I’m able to get information about files, stored on a drive. However, since certain time my files have begun being uploaded empty. Function, which uploads a file is very simple:

```vb
Private Function UploadSingleFile(ByVal FileNM As String) As File
    FilesBody = New File
    FilesParentFolders = New List(Of ParentReference)
    FilesParentReference = New ParentReference
    FilesParentReference.Id = RootFolderID
    FilesParentFolders.Add(FilesParentReference)
    FilesBody.Parents = FilesParentFolders
    FilesBody.Title = Path.GetFileName(FileNM)
    FilesBody.Description = Path.GetFileName(FileNM)
    FilesByteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileNM)
    FilesStream = New MemoryStream(FilesByteArray)
    FilesRequest = MyService.Files.Insert(FilesBody, FilesStream, "")
    FilesRequest.Convert = False : FilesRequest.Ocr = False
    FilesRequest.ChunkSize = 262144
    FilesRequest.Upload()
    Return FilesRequest.ResponseBody
End Function
```

Earlier this function worked well. But today it returns empty file with only Title present, without WebContentLink and with Size=0 bytes. Have I reached some limit of requests or it may be server temporarily unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

i'm getting the same errors trying to upload a file with mime type "text/csv" with the "convert" option set, and instead of creating a spreadsheet like it used it, now it's creating an empty folder.

looking into updating the API client to the new 1.0 version from .6... but the new API client is not compatible with the old version, so it's a complete rewrite.

not happy with google today.